# Checking for a null reference?

Tags: c++

Lets say you have something like this:

```
int& refint;
int* foo =0;
refint = *foo;
```

How could you verify if the reference is `NULL` to avoid a crash?

Comment: You drag the developer who wrote that into a dark room with one chair and one light shining on it.  Then you burn them with cigarettes until they repent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't late-initialize a reference like that.  It has to be initialized when it's declared.

On Visual C++ I get

> error C2530: 'refint' : references
>   must be initialized

with your code.

If you 'fix' the code, the crash (strictly, undefined behaviour) happens at reference usage time in VC++ v10.

```
int* foo = 0;
int& refint(*foo);
int i(refint);  // access violation here
```

The way to make this safe is to check the pointer at reference initialization or assignment time.

```
int* foo =0;
if (foo)
{
  int& refint(*foo);
  int i(refint);
}
```

though that still does not guarantee `foo` points to usable memory, nor that it remains so while the reference is in scope.

Comment: "the crash will happen at reference init time" - promise? ;-)

Comment: The crash needn't (and often doesn't) happen at reference init time. with UB anything could happen, including no crash.

Comment: @Charles, checked my assumptions in debugger and edited.  It crashes only in VC++ when I use the reference.  UB all round...

Answer (score 5):

You don't, by the time you have a "null" reference you already have undefined behaviour. You should always check whether a pointer is null before trying to form a reference by dereferencing the pointer.

(Your code is illegal; you can't create an uninitialized reference and try and bind it by assigning it; you can only bind it during initialization.)

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can't.

Whoever "creates a null reference" (or tries to, I should say) has already invoked undefined behavior, so the code might (or might not) crash before you get a chance to check anything.

Whoever created the reference should have done:

```
int *foo = 0;
if (foo) {
    int &refint = *foo;
    ... use refint for something ...
}
```

Normally it's considered the caller's problem if they've written `*foo` when `foo` is null, and it's not one function's responsibility to check for that kind of error in the code of other functions. But you could litter things like `assert(&refint);` through your code. They might help catch errors made by your callers, since after all for any function you write there's a reasonable chance the caller is yourself.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers above are correct, but if for some reason you want to do this I thought at least one person should provide an answer. I am currently trying to track down a bad reference in some source code and it would be useful to see if someone has deleted this reference and set it to null at some point. Hopefully this wont generate to many down votes.

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        int* foo = nullptr;
        int& refint = *foo;

        if(&refint == nullptr)
            std::cout << "Null" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Value " << refint << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

> Null

Comment: Note: output is Null in this case because int *foo; just happened to be nullptr. Since it is uninitialized it could be anything. I would initialize it to nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

To make the above code compile, you will have to switch the order:

```
int* foo =0;
int& refint = *foo; // on actual PCs, this code will crash here
```

(There may be older processor or runtime architectures where this worked.)

Answer (score 0):

....saying all of the above, if you *do* want to have a null reference, use `boost::optional<>`, works like a charm..

Answer (score -5):

You don't need to, references cannot be null.

Read the manual.